# web api post method do not work in flutter

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, flutter-web

I did everything which i found in internet, but still its not working...

The web api is .net core 5

```dart
http.Response response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(ss),
        headers:
        {
          "Access_Control_Allow_Methods": "POST, OPTIONS",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": 'true'
        },
        body: _buyBasket
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must change your API .net core to .net core 6.0 to resolve your problem
happy code

Comment: I test it in one Web Api with .net core 6 and it worked! Thankful!

Comment: @Arash Ghazi Why? Can you please add details

Comment: unfortunately, I haven't found the reason but I just convert my API to .net core 6, and the problem was solved.